# Must restart to see new program run on MSP430

Tags: msp430

I can't seem to find an answer to my question. I'm programming MSP320 via JTAG using MSP-FET. When I upload new code, I can see Mode LED blink, indicating there's a data transfer, then both Power and Mode LED stays on and nothing happens. When I power off and on the chip, then the program executes.

I was expecting the new code to execute, but I have to restart power to see that happen. Is this an expected behavior? If yes, any tips on how to make chip execute new program without power restart?

Answer (score 0):

There can be reasons for NOT executing code at the initial programming stage. (For example: Untested PCB with possible short-circuits. No dependant hardware connected. No configuration etc.) It is therefore often the default for the programmer tool to not release reset after programming. Cycling the power has the side-effect of breaking the JTAG connection.

You didn't say what programming software you're using, but in the MSP-FET  configuration dialogue, search for the term "Hold in Reset" after programming.